# Backprop in Tensor flow -- accuracy does not improve with increased hidden layer size

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm using the "MNIST for ML Beginners" code template from the Tensorflow site to develop a network for predicting a single output. I've changed the hidden layer size from 10 to 100 with no change in the test accuracy (0.14375 in each case) afer about 30,000 training sets. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the way I've constructed the input variables or just the way I've implemented the code. If someone could take a look I'd appreciate it:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
train_data = np.genfromtxt("PERSON1RATING_TRAINING.txt", delimiter="    ")
train_input = train_data[:, :10]
train_input = train_input.reshape(29440, 10)
X_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [29440, 10])

train_target = train_data[:, 10]
train_target = train_target.reshape(29440, 1)
Y_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [29440, 1])

test_data = np.genfromtxt("PERSON1RATING_TEST.txt", delimiter=" ")
test_input = test_data[:, :10]
test_input = test_input.reshape(5120, 10)
X_test = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5120, 10])

test_target = test_data[:, 10]
test_target = test_target.reshape(5120, 1)
Y_test = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5120, 1])

W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10, 100]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
H = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X_train, W_1) + b)
H_test = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X_test, W_1) + b)

W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 1]))
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(H, W_2))
Y_obt_test = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(H_test, W_2))

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y_train * tf.log(Y), 
reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(29440):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X_train: train_input, 
    Y_train:train_target})

Y = tf.nn.sigmoid(Y)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(Y_obt_test), Y_test)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X_test : test_input, Y_test: test_target}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope these will help

```
# use random_normal initializer for all weights, not biases
# W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10, 100]))
W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10, 100]))

# No softmax for the training logits
# Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(H, W_2))
Y = tf.matmul(H, W_2)
cross_entropy =  tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Y, labels=Y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. In response to the cross_entropy definition you suggested, I get the following error message: "ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2)."Any idea why this is?

Comment: Are you using one_hot encoded labels? You may use 1D labels tensor, removing the one_hot encoding

Comment: Nope, I'm not using the one_hot labels. Also, I tried reshaping Y to the same dimensions as Y_train, but got "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'reshape'."

Comment: Y should be 2D `tensor` and the labels `Y_train` should be 1D `tensor`.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but can you explain what the extra dimension in Y is? (Also, I tried using tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits, where dimensions can be the same, but that returned the original problem, accuracy was still 14%). Thank you!